# How does the function localtime() used?

Tags: c, linux, function, datetime, gcc

I am trying to understand what the statement below is doing:

```
tmptr = localtime(&t);
```

The complete code is:

```
main() {
    char dateString[20], timeString[20];
    struct tm *tmptr;
    time_t t;
    t = time(NULL);
    tmptr = localtime(&t);
    strftime(dateString, 20, "%F",tmptr)
    printf("%s %s\n",dateString,timeString);
}
```

I understand that the function `time(NULL)` gives the time in seconds from the UNIX Epoch. But I do not understand why:

1. `NULL` passed in `time()`? What if I pass a non-null value? I couldn't understand the man page here.
2. What does the `localtime()` actually do here?

Answer (score 1):

The man page is quite clear about that parameter:

> ```
> time_t time(time_t *t);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If `t` is non-`NULL`, the return value is also stored in the memory
>   pointed to by `t`.

This means you can either use it like this:

```
time t;
t = time(NULL);
```

or like this:

```
time t;
time(&t);
```

As you correctly recognized the result in t is the number of seconds since the epoch.
If you want to get some human readable date and time you need to transform it via [localtime()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime)

Comment: I see. I was earlier thinking that it meant that it was about adding the value passed to the epoch time. Its clear now. Thanks.

Comment: I could print the desired time format via using the structure in localtime( ). Isn't it? If so, then why strftime could be used?

Comment: Not directly in one step. You get a structure holding values for day, month, hour, minute, etc. You can use these to print them separately. If you want to get a complete string at once you need to use `asctime()`. Or you pass the broken down parameters into strftime. Read the man page to get the finer details.

Answer (score 1):

[`time()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time) is a very old function of the C lib. `time_t time(time_t *t);` Like you see, the prototype say that `time` take a `time_t *` as argument and return a `time_t`. This mean that you can have the result with two way. You can do like you do or:

```
time_t t;
if ((time_t)-1 == time(&t)) {
  perror("time()");
  return 1;
}
```

If you do [`time(NULL)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/time), the function must not stock the result in the pointer `time_t *` because the man say:

> If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory
>   pointed to by t.

[`localtime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) convert the number of second since the Epoch and split it in years, month, etc.. You should use [`localtime_r()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) because it's thread safe.

```
struct tm result;
if (localtime_r(&t, &result) == NULL) {
  return 1;
}
```